# Is there seccomp analogue for Windows

Tags: windows, seccomp

Is there something like [seccomp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seccomp) that works on Windows?

It should limit all syscalls to some very limited set, like only reading and writing to already opened files.

The one described as [sandbox for Chromium](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/sandbox) does not look like Seccomp, as it is based on usual file permissions and Windows security objects, not on limiting access to syscalls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is nothing like seccomp that works on Windows. The closest there is are traditional permissions which disable certain privileged syscalls. But currently, there is no way to whitelist or blacklist entire arbitrary syscalls, or syscall arguments on Windows.

Answer (score 4):

Since Windows 8 you can block all calls from `win32k.sys` with `DisallowWin32kSystemCalls` flag in [`PROCESS_MITIGATION_SYSTEM_CALL_DISABLE_POLICY` structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh871472(v=vs.85).aspx).

You can't gradually control system calls as it in seccomp, but this is still an interesting feature.

Answer (score 0):

> Elasticsearch uses seccomp in Linux, Seatbelt in macOS, and ActiveProcessLimit on Windows as additional security layers to prevent Elasticsearch from forking or running other processes.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/modules-scripting-security.html

Comment: `ActiveProcessLimit` seems to be about resource limits (how many processes can be spawned or something like that), not restriction of what OS features can be used.